# Cordova InAppBrowser plugin freezing the app

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

We have a hybrid cordova based iOS app. We are using the InAppBrowser plugin to open an url in mobile Safari using the code below:

```
window.open(encodeURI(appurl), '_system', options);
```

This takes the user out of our app and opens mobile safari browser and tries to load the url. If, while the url is still loading, we tap the 'Back to myApp' button of iOS to return to our app, the app is frozen. The UI does not respond to taps or any events. In the logs, I continue to see these lines:

```
2017-02-21 22:36:33.343 myESS[6467:1487510] in open
2017-02-21 22:36:33.344 myESS[6467:1487510] THREAD WARNING: ['InAppBrowser'] took '18.220947' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2017-02-21 22:36:33.363 myESS[6467:1487510] in open
2017-02-21 22:36:33.364 myESS[6467:1487510] THREAD WARNING: ['InAppBrowser'] took '19.006836' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2017-02-21 22:36:33.383 myESS[6467:1487510] in open
2017-02-21 22:36:33.383 myESS[6467:1487510] THREAD WARNING: ['InAppBrowser'] took '19.141113' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

These logs go on for a while. The url I am trying to load is simply http://www.google.com. The log statements continue for several seconds. Then the logs stop, I am automatically taken out of my app to mobile safari browser. 
If I now go back to the myApp, the UI is responsive.

Any ideas on why the plugin behaves this way? The plugin `open` method is getting called multiple times automatically and it freezes up the app UI until the url is loaded. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Comment: I think you are calling open multiple times

Comment: You are right. It was an issue on our side. An incorrect loop around the open call somewhere was causing this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet might help you

```
setTimeout(function(){ _self.openUrl(url) },300);
```